# Why form in a form doesn't work in internet explorer

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal, webforms

I add a form from code behind to `asp:PlaceHolder` control.
When I add form to `placeholder` `<form>` tags are missing.
Asp.net removes it from some reason.

But I have found workaround for this. I have added (*empty form*):

```
<form></form>
<form... my form code that comes from code behind...
```

And this works fine in all browsers except **IE**!
Any idea how to workaround this in **IE**.

(**Maybe this is important**) This form is actually a **PayPal button code** and I get it from data source.
 
I need to add 10 buttons on page:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">           
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the dissadvanced of the asp.net webforms is **that only one asp.net form is allowed** in a normal asp.net page. One form that have the `runat="server"` and inside that form only the asp.net controls correctly work and cooporate with the code behind.

However you can break that - but not continue to have the same asp.net functionallyty. What you can do is to use a LiteralControl and direct render on the page the PayPal button code and only before just close the global form by using the `</form>`. Only the close just before add the new ones.

Now the moment you do that, you must forget the post back on the same page and actually have it only for post to PP. The only way to have some asp.net page functionallyty is to keep it before the first form close, and set on web.config the option to keep the validation on top.

So you start with

```
<form  name="aspnetForm" method="post" action="/ui/login.aspx?ReturnUrl=General.aspx" >
  ... some controls that post back to aspx page    
</form>
```

and you end up with

```
<form  name="aspnetForm" method="post" action="/ui/login.aspx?ReturnUrl=General.aspx" >
  ... some controls that post back to aspx page    
  ... up to here maybe the buttons will work for the page, after that not any more
 </form> //<---- added by you
  // follow the PayPal buttons
  <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">           
  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" ... >
  </form>

  // second button, etc
  <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">           
  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" ... >
  </form>
// now this close form is orphan....
</form>
```

Alternative you can make post redirect, but require a lot more code and  a middle page that create the PayPal post data on code behind. Here is an example http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37539/Redirect-and-POST-in-ASP-NET

The same trick you can do it with javascript, create a form using javascript on the fly and post that to the paypal button, all on the same page with javascript.

I have use all that techniques, all of them works.

Comment: This first sentence is misleading. You can only have one form with `runat=server`, but you can have many forms in one ASP.NET page as long as they aren't nested. There is no reason that you have to wrap your entire document in a form, though that is how most webforms templates work.

Comment: @MikeSmithDev You have a point, I will change it (or you can if you like to correct what you believe)

Comment: I still didn't figure this. But I found this article http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36071/Implementing-Non-ASP-NET-Posts-in-ASP-NET and solution looks perfect to me the only problem is that I need to have 5 buttons on one page and don't know is this possible with this solution maybe?

Comment: @1110 Yes this is the middle page solution, after the post is create a page that automatic make the post. The only issue here is that you see a white page for one second.

Comment: But how to use this to put 6 buttons on one page (solution from the link that I posted in previous comment)?

Comment: @1110 See this solution, is more clear and the same with your likn http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37539/Redirect-and-POST-in-ASP-NET