# Creating buttons with PayPal

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal

I'm working in a ASP.NET web application and I am trying to create simple Pay Now buttons for PayPal payment.

So I got this link that says I can create JavaScript buttons by copying and pasting that code.

http://paypal.github.io/JavaScriptButtons/

So I downloaded the javascript file, included it on the ASPX page and start coding this:

This is the div in the ASPX page that is going to show the dynamic create form code:

```
<div id="divPagamentoPaypal" runat="server" class="msgbox_container" style="text-align: left;">    
    <div class="msgbox_title">
        Pagamento de PayPal
    </div>               
    <div id="divPayPal" style="align-content:center;" runat="server">
        <asp:Label ID="lblPayPalButton" runat="server" Text="qewqeqweq"></asp:Label>
    </div>
</div>
```

this is the code-behind:

```
    string form = "<form action='https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr' method='post' target='_top'>";
    form += "<INPUT TYPE='hidden' NAME='return' value='" + BackUrl + "'>";
    form += "<input type='hidden' name='cmd' value='_s-xclick'>";

    form += "<script src='paypal-button.min.js?merchant=" + Settings.Current.MerchantID + "'" +
                    "data-button='buynow'" +
                    "data-name='" + AccaoParaConsulta.ObterAccao(this.DataSource, p.IdAccao).NomeAccao + "'" +
                    "data-amount='" + p.Valor.ToString("#.00") + "'" +
                    "async" +
                    "></script>";
    form += "<input type='image' src='https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif' border='0' name='submit' alt='PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!'/>";
    form += "</form>";
    lblPayPalButton.Text = form;
```

Needless to say that this does not work.

All I need to do is to create buttons, Pay Now only, and they need to be created by the data coming from the SQL data base.

I really think I am doing this all wrong, PayPal website seems very confusing and there is stuff all over the place, they just aren't clear on what we need to do.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at that similar answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16262481/why-form-in-a-form-doesnt-work-in-internet-explorer/16262979#16262979

Comment: The main issue is that form is handle by asp.net, and when you add other form inside the asp.net then you break it... and you need to work around that issue. More to read http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Basp.net%5D+%5Bpaypal%5D+buttons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traditional ASP.Net doesn't allow multiple form tag. *It is not an issue in ASP.Net MVC.*

You want to replace Label with Button control, and redirect to PayPal with values in query string.

For example,

```
protected void BuyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string url = TestMode ? 
      "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr" : 
      "https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr";

   var builder = new StringBuilder();
   builder.Append(url);
   builder.AppendFormat("?cmd=_xclick&business={0}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Email));
   builder.Append("&lc=US&no_note=0&currency_code=USD");
   builder.AppendFormat("&item_name={0}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(ItemName));
   builder.AppendFormat("&invoice={0}", TransactionId);
   builder.AppendFormat("&amount={0}", Amount);
   builder.AppendFormat("&return={0}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(ReturnUrl));
   builder.AppendFormat("&cancel_return={0}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(CancelUrl));
   builder.AppendFormat("&undefined_quantity={0}", Quantity);
   builder.AppendFormat("&item_number={0}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(ItemNumber));

   Response.Redirect(builder.ToString());
}
```

Comment: yeap it worked, were is this in PayPal documentation? hehe, thks :)